# Seleniumwire copy or create new request from an existing one

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver, seleniumwire

I am intercepting a request and i want to send it many times with different parameters, I know how modify a request but I havent found a way to send the same request more times modifying the value of a parameter.

Is it possible using Seleniumwire or should I use other librarys like requests or http.client to copy and send it manually.

Thanks for your beautiful time :)

I tried using an interceptor but it only returns the same request modified. No idea how to copy it usign seleniumwire.